# Elastic Search for Symfony 3.1

Tags: elasticsearch, frameworks, symfony-3.1

Does FOSElasticaBundle has compatibility with Symfony 3.1? I have seen the documentation at github but it's for Symfony 2. Any resource available for elastic search with symfony 3.1?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks Nehal actually i have tried this link with symfony 3.1 but FOS Bundle is not installing saying an incompatibility error https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle